# map multiple columns by a single dictionary in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, mapping

I have a DataFrame with a multiple columns with 'yes' and 'no' strings. I want all of them to convert to a boolian dtype. To map one column, I would use

```
dict_map_yn_bool={'yes':True, 'no':False}
df['nearby_subway_station'].map(dict_map_yn_bool)
```

This would do the job for the one column. how can I replace multiple columns with single line of code?

Comment: Pandas equivalent to a `for` loop is `apply`: `df = df.apply(lambda x: x.map(dict_map_yn_bool))`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use a `stack`/`unstack` idiom

```
df.stack().map(dict_map_yn_bool).unstack()
```

Using @jezrael's setup

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'nearby_subway_station':['yes','no'], 'Station':['no','yes']})
dict_map_yn_bool={'yes':True, 'no':False}
```

Then

```
df.stack().map(dict_map_yn_bool).unstack()

  Station nearby_subway_station
0   False                  True
1    True                 False
```

---

***timing***
*small data*

[image]

*bigger data*

[image]

Comment: Yes, I think down vote is not good idea. This is nice solution also.

Comment: Thanks @jezrael.  Also, this is a general idiom that can be applied to many scenarios in which you want to use a `pd.Series` specific method on many columns.

Comment: I think converting to `Series` and then back is not good idea - reshaping is very slow. So in my opinion better is avoid it.

Comment: @jezrael if the size of the dataframe is small and performance isn't the focus, then this can be a simple and intuitive solution.

Comment: I think `replace` is here number one, then `applymap` and last `stack/unstack`. Btw, what about performance of `for x in df:
    df[x] = df[x].map(dict_map_yn_bool)` ?

Comment: In my opinion it can be faster as `stack/unstack` solution.

Comment: You are correct!  However, *if* performance isn't the concern then it is the preference of OP as to which style they choose.

Comment: with map and applymap, the value gets replaced to NaN / None. With replace, if its not found in dict, then it stays as is. Thats one more thing to consider.

Answer (score 15):

You can use [`applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'nearby_subway_station':['yes','no'], 'Station':['no','yes']})
print (df)
  Station nearby_subway_station
0      no                   yes
1     yes                    no

dict_map_yn_bool={'yes':True, 'no':False}

df = df.applymap(dict_map_yn_bool.get)
print (df)
  Station nearby_subway_station
0   False                  True
1    True                 False
```

Another solution:

```
for x in df:
    df[x] = df[x].map(dict_map_yn_bool)
print (df)
  Station nearby_subway_station
0   False                  True
1    True                 False
```

Thanks [Jon Clements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43725799/map-multiple-columns-by-a-single-dictionary-in-pandas#comment74495419_43725843) for very nice idea - using [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

```
df = df.replace({'yes': True, 'no': False})
print (df)
  Station nearby_subway_station
0   False                  True
1    True                 False
```

Some differences if data are no in `dict`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'nearby_subway_station':['yes','no','a'], 'Station':['no','yes','no']})
print (df)
  Station nearby_subway_station
0      no                   yes
1     yes                    no
2      no                     a
```

`applymap` create `None` for `boolean`, `strings`, for numeric `NaN`.

```
df = df.applymap(dict_map_yn_bool.get)
print (df)
  Station nearby_subway_station
0   False                  True
1    True                 False
2   False                  None
```

`map` create  `NaN`:

```
for x in df:
    df[x] = df[x].map(dict_map_yn_bool)

print (df)
  Station nearby_subway_station
0   False                  True
1    True                 False
2   False                   NaN
```

`replace` dont create `NaN` or `None`, but original data are untouched:

```
df = df.replace(dict_map_yn_bool)
print (df)
  Station nearby_subway_station
0   False                  True
1    True                 False
2   False                     a
```

Comment: Why not just `df.replace({'yes': True, 'no': False})` ?

Comment: @JonClements why not just add that as a perfectly good answer so we can upvote it because it's a good one?  That said, I'd say having a goto method for using `map` across multiple columns is useful.  Even you could use `replace` in this context.

Comment: @piRSquared well - to me it seems obvious - but I'm well aware I'm still nowhere near the level of others when it comes to pandas... so it's a question and I'm happy to have the suggestion added to the answer so we've got a good reference for anyone else. I just don't know if it has any pros/cons that I can't see etc... so wasn't willing to add as an answer is all.

Comment: @JonClements Sometimes we get lost in the question, we forget all the other ways to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: @piRSquared indeed. We've got a good answer now anyway covering all aspects. If jezreal wanted to put in some details about the difference between applymap, map and replace (hint hint)... we've between us got a fantastic answer for others in future.

Comment: You can also supply the `value` argument to `df.replace` to make it work the same way as `.map` if required

Comment: @JonClements - `value`? Do you think `df = df.replace(dict_map_yn_bool, value=np.nan)`? But it doesnt work. Or something missing?

Comment: @piRSquared see - that why's I only comment :p

Comment: @JonClements - no problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would work with pandas.DataFrame.replace as I think it is the simplest and has built-in arguments to support this task. Also a one-liner solution, as requested.

First case, replace all instances of 'yes' or 'no':

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy import random

# Generating the data, 20 rows by 5 columns.
data = random.choice(['yes','no'], size=(20, 5), replace=True)
col_names = ['col_{}'.format(a) for a in range(1,6)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=col_names)

# Supplying lists of values to what they will replace. No dict needed.
df_bool = df.replace(to_replace=['yes','no'], value=[True, False])
```

Second case, where you only want to replace in a subset of columns, as described in the documentation for DataFrame.replace. Use a nested dictionary where the first set of keys are columns with values to replace, and values are dictionaries mapping values to their replacements:

```
dict_map_yn_bool={'yes':True, 'no':False}
replace_dict = {'col_1':dict_map_yn_bool, 
           'col_2':dict_map_yn_bool}
df_bool = df.replace(to_replace=replace_dict)
```