# Use list to map subset of dataframe columns to dictionary values

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to pass a list of columns to map a dictionary's values in a single call?

I can do it by stating each column but wondering if I can shorten up the syntax.

Looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43725799/map-multiple-columns-by-a-single-dictionary-in-pandas) for reference.

Sample data:

```
import pandas as pd
 
# initialize data of lists.
data = {'id': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
        'col1': ['PHX', 'BKN', 'X', 'PHX', 'X'],
        'col2': ['X', 'PHX', 'BKN', 'BKN', 'X'],
        'col3': ['PHX', 'BKN', 'PHX', 'BKN', 'PHX']
       }
 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df

  id col1 col2 col3
0  a  PHX    X  PHX
1  b  BKN  PHX  BKN
2  c    X  BKN  PHX
3  d  PHX  BKN  BKN
4  e    X    X  PHX
```

I want to apply this mapping to `col1` and `col2` but not `col3`:

```
name_dict = {'PHX' : 'PHO', 'BKN': 'NJN'}
```

So `PHX -> PHO` and `BKN -> NJN`.

This replaces all cols but I want a subset of columns:

```
df = df.replace(name_dict)
```

Daisy-chaining 'replace' works:

```
df = df.replace({'col1': name_dict}).replace({'col2': name_dict})
```

This also works:

```
df = df.replace({'col1': name_dict, 'col2': name_dict})
```

Can I shorten this up a bit, something like:

```
df = df.replace({['col1', 'col2']: name_dict})
```

However, this results in `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`.

Desired output (`col1` and `col2` values updated but not `col3`):

```
  id col1 col2 col3
0  a  PHO    X  PHX
1  b  NJN  PHO  BKN
2  c    X  NJN  PHX
3  d  PHO  NJN  BKN
4  e    X    X  PHX
```

Comment: what about `df[['col1', 'col2']] = df[['col1', 'col2']].replace(name_dict)`?

Comment: What about `df = df.replace({c:name_dict for c in ["col1", "col2"]})` that uses a list of columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`dict.fromkeys`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys):

```
df.replace(dict.fromkeys(['col1', 'col2'], name_dict))
```

Or, if you want to modify in place, with a list of columns:

```
cols = ['col1', 'col2']
df[cols] = df[cols].replace(name_dict)
```

Output:

```
  id col1 col2 col3
0  a  PHO    X  PHX
1  b  NJN  PHO  BKN
2  c    X  NJN  PHX
3  d  PHO  NJN  BKN
4  e    X    X  PHX
```